# Wordpress redirection - login cookie error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, cookies

I have a wordpress installation at www.example.com
I have a new domain (www.promo-example.com) which is redirected to www.example.com/promo (but keeps the url www.promo-example.com)

There is a login box with a form which is submitted with ajax and if the login is successfull, redirects with javascript to a page (www.example.com/only-for-users) which is visible only for logged in users. From the original domain, wordpress sets the correct cookies, and everything works good.
BUT from the new domain, it does not set any cookies. Thus the login is successfull, the JS gets the success trigger and redirects to that page, but there the `is_user_logged_in()` returns false and sends it back to a separate login page.

Is there a way to set somehow the cookies, or what workaround can be for this problem? What I saw is that on www.promo-example.com there is no wordpress cookies set, but on the original one, it sets the default settings cookies.

Comment: You can set cookies with JS. Using `document.cookie="id=value; path=/";`  
Or in PHP as: `setcookie($id, $value);`

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is set for the current domain with the path set as `/` by default, so when the site is redirected to your other domain, the cookie does not apply. This is due to security reasons and so the cookie will not be set.

An alternative would be to use a unique ID that is generated on the original page, that is then posted to the new page which picks this up using GET or POST.

This will allow you to make sure that they are logged in.

For example, you could send it via post as (on your first page):

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/promo" method="POST">
    <input name="logged_in" type="text">
</form>
```

Then on your `/promo` page, it can recieve it as:

```
if (isset($_POST['logged_in'])) {
    $is_user_logged_in = true;
}
```

Or something along those lines :)